# Python: Z score parameters computation

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am aware of rolling z score computation using Python.

Given the raw score and z score, is it possible to compute rolling window used to compute the mean of raw score? Please suggest the way forward.

```
def zscore(x, window):
    r = x.rolling(window=window)
    m = r.mean().shift(1)
    s = r.std(ddof=0).shift(1)
    z = (x-m)/s
    return z



import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



raw1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1),  columns=list('A'))

z_score1=zscore(raw1,20)
```

Now, I have only raw score and z score with equal number of observations.

```
raw2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1),  columns=list('A'))
z_score2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 1),  columns=list('A'))
```

How to calculate the number of observations used to compute the z score given that both raw2 and z_score2 both have equal number of observations?
Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know of any optimization functions that will handle the integer constraint required.

Depending on the size of your data, I'd propose a brute force approach. The following works fine.

```
raw2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
zscore2 = zscore(raw2, 30)

err = pd.Series()
for widow in range(1, zscore2.shape[0]):
    err.loc[widow] = (zscore2 - zscore(raw2, widow)).abs().sum()

err.idxmin()
```